# how to add a child instance to the "many" end of one-to-many

Tags: flask, flask-restless

I have two models in my flask / restless app: Blueprint and Workload
The Blueprint should have a collection of Workloads.

Here are the models:

```
class Blueprint(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True)
    description = db.Column(db.String(250), unique=True)


class Workload(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True)
    description = db.Column(db.String(250), unique=True)
    image = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True)
    flavor = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True)
    blueprint_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('blueprint.id'))
    blueprint = db.relationship(Blueprint, backref='workloads')


db.create_all()

# Create the Flask-Restless API manager.
manager = flask.ext.restless.APIManager(app, flask_sqlalchemy_db=db)

# Create API endpoints, which will be available at /api/<tablename> by
# default. Allowed HTTP methods can be specified as well.
manager.create_api(Blueprint, methods=['GET', 'PUT', 'POST', 'DELETE'])
manager.create_api(Workload, methods=['GET', 'PUT', 'POST', 'DELETE'])
```

What is the right syntax, either with curl or with python, to add a Workload instance to Blueprint's 'workloads' collection?

Comment: Hi Eugene - please avoid adding tags to the title of your question as this does not help identify or highlight your question; instead use the tagging system.

Answer (score 1):

Finally figured the answer:   to add a Workload to Blueprint as a child:   curl --request PATCH -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{ "blueprint": { "id": 1 } }'  http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/workload/1      Given the Model definitions above, this does exactly what's needed.     Then, when we run curl -i -X GET -H "Accept: application/json" http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/blueprint/1     we get a specific Blueprint along with a list of Workloads that belong to it